# How to use onPress function on a buttonlist in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Suppose I have a list of elevated button.

```
List<ElevatedButton> buttonsList = [];
```

Now I want to use onpress function to that list.Like if I press `buttonList[i]` then only onpress function will work for`buttonList[i]`not for the whole list. For example I want to change color of third button then only third button will change color, not all the button of the list.Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: how you are adding item on `buttonsList`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a list of properties that generate a list of buttons?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh From the user input. User input a sentence ,I break the word of the sentance in list and make buttons from the list

Comment: @Chance I am absolutely new to flutter. So do not know how to do that

Comment: You can save the colors `list` by the index., or using a `Map<int, Color>`, or using a `model` to hold the color state for each button.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use value as @Chance said, but for curiosity purpose, test this widget.

```dart
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  List<ElevatedButton> buttonsList = [];
  int _currentItem = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        //list of buttons
        ...buttonsList.map((e) => e),

        //To create one
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(
              () {
                final value = _currentItem.toInt(); // creating new value , dont use `_currentItem` direclty, check pass by value vs reference
                buttonsList.add(
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("Tapped item $value");
                    },
                    child: Text("item $value"),
                  ),
                );

                _currentItem++;
              },
            );
          },
          child: Text("add ${_currentItem + 1}"),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I would do with a list of properties this way. See if it helps you. Whenever you insert a new property into the list the element will appear in the listview unselected.

```
class ButtonProperties {
  String label;
  Color color;
  bool selected;

  ButtonProperties(
      {required this.label, this.color = Colors.black, this.selected = false});
}

class MyButtonList extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyButtonList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyButtonListState createState() => _MyButtonListState();
}

class _MyButtonListState extends State<MyButtonList> {
  List<ButtonProperties> buttonsList = [
    ButtonProperties(label: 'Button 1'),
    ButtonProperties(label: 'Button 2'),
    ButtonProperties(label: 'Button 3'),
    ButtonProperties(label: 'Button 4'),
    ButtonProperties(label: 'Button 5'),
    ButtonProperties(label: 'Button 6'),
    ButtonProperties(label: 'Button 7'),
    ButtonProperties(label: 'Button 8'),
    ButtonProperties(label: 'Button 9'),
  ];

  void _onChangeButtonColor(int index) {
    setState(() {
      if (buttonsList[index].selected) {
        buttonsList[index].selected = false;
        buttonsList[index].color = Colors.black;
      } else {
        buttonsList[index].selected = true;
        buttonsList[index].color = Colors.red;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Button List')),
      body: ListView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
          itemCount: buttonsList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => _onChangeButtonColor(index),
                child: Text(
                  '${buttonsList[index].label}',
                  style: TextStyle(color: buttonsList[index].color),
                ));
          }),
    );
  }
}
```